# Is the official client for the YouTube API thread-safe?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, gdata-api, gdata-python-client

I'm using the [official Python client for the YouTube API](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) (called `gdata.youtube.service`.) My question: Is it thread-safe?

For example, I want to do both `GetUserFavoritesFeed` and `GetYouTubeUserFeed` at the same time in two parallel threads. Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably safe if you create a separate API instance for each thread.